# Python FastText: How to create a corpus from a Dataframe Column

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, nlp, fasttext

- I need to create a **corpus** for my Email Classifer .
  Right now am Using **fasttext 0.8.3** but it expects text file as a input whereas 
  i need to pass a dataframe as an input .
- It shows error while i am Using following Code :-

  ```

  import fasttext

  ````
  x_val = df['Message']  
  y_val = df['Categories']  
  model = fasttext.skipgram(x_val, y_val)  
  print model.words

  TypeError:
  <ipython-input-105-58241a9688b5> 
   <module>() 
  ----> 1 model = fasttext.skipgram(x_val, y_val) 
        2 print model.words # list of words in dictionary 
        fasttext/fasttext.pyx in fasttext.fasttext.skipgram (fasttext/fasttext.cpp:6451)() 
        fasttext/fasttext.pyx in fasttext.fasttext.train_wrapper (fasttext/fasttext.cpp:5223)() 
       /root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/genericpath.pyc in isfile(path) 
             35 """Test whether a path is a regular file""" 
             36 try: 
        ---> 37 st = os.stat(path) 
             38 except os.error: 
             39 return False 
       TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Series found

  ```
  ````

  - In above code the *df['Message'] and df['Categories']* are the dataframe column in which it contains mails and the category respectively .
  - There are 30123 mails in the dataframe .
  - I already go through the Documentation of fasttext but i dont find someting useful.

  [Fasttext Tutorial refrence](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fasttext)

  Thanks for the Help.

Comment: Since `x_val` is a series (when you slice a dataframe you get a series) you can use `x_val.to_string()`, to convert it to a string or buffer. Documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_string.html).

Comment: ValueError : <type 'str'>:  
(<type 'exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError'>, UnicodeEncodeError('ascii', u'fastText: cannot load

Comment: __ValueError__ : fasttext : cannot load